# Building documentation for Ember Data

Tags: documentation, ember-data

There is a *lot of documentation* in Ember Data source code. I wonder, how I can build the Ember Data documentation? I tried,

```
bundle exec rake docs
bundle exec rake docs:build
bundle exec rake docs:preview
```

But, no luck so far...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/) first.
2. run `yuidocs .` in the dist folder where ember-data.js is

Documentation will be by default in a directory call `out`

UPDATE:
This seems only to generate docs for Ember and not Ember-data. I also tried [JSDoc3](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) but i got an exception.

Comment: Confirmed, this method generates documentation, but it's only ember docs not ember-data docs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/890)  would help

And also a working [online api documentation](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80097157/ember-data/index.html) for Ember-Data

Answer (score 0):

```
ember build -e production
cd dist\docs
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 3000
```